# GCP Data Catalog - BigQuery gcloud Command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How to change between enumerated values of a field in a Data Catalog Tag Attached to a BigQuery Dataset using gcloud command?

I am able to manually change the value, let us say the enumerated values are Happy and sad, I am able to swap between sad and Happy manually but, I want to execute it using gcloud command.

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax is:

`gcloud beta data-catalog entries update [ENTRY_ID] --location=[LOCATION] --update-mask=[FIELD_NAME] --type=[TAG_TYPE] [FIELD_NAME]=[NEW_VALUE]`

Where:

> LOCATION is the location of the Data Catalog instance that contains the entry

> TAG_TYPE is the type of the tag you want to update

> NEW_VALUE is the new value you want to set for the field

> FIELD_NAME is the name of the field you want to update

field named emotion from "sad" to "happy", you would use the following command:

`gcloud beta data-catalog entries update [ENTRY_ID] --location=[LOCATION] --update-mask=emotion --type=[TAG_TYPE] emotion=happy`

Comment: But, I want to swap between values in enumerated field, say I have a BigQuery dataset and a Tag template is attached to it, it has a tag named status and the options are success and failure, I want to swap between these values within the BigQuery Dataset

Comment: and what should come at the place of ENTRY_ID

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the gcloud beta data-catalog entries update [ENTRY_ID] command, replace [ENTRY_ID] with the actual ID of the entry you want to update. The ID is unique and can be found by using gcloud beta data-catalog entries list.